# CoreNLP training dataset AnCora for Spanish language

Tags: stanford-nlp

I'm looking for Spanish training dataset AnCora for CoreNLP, specifically this one [IARG-AnCora Spanish (AnCora 3.0.1)](http://clic.ub.edu/corpus/webfm_send/95). The website requires a registration. I created an account, tried to register on the [website](http://clic.ub.edu/corpus/en/user/register), but account has never been activated. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks, Victor

Answer (score 0):

There is info about training a dependency parser model, including where to find UD data here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/depparse.html